# htm file not loaded in Angular JS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I tried to do coding in `AngularJS` the

> HTML file is not getting loaded while using templateUrl

my Html code,

```
 index.htm

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="nav-bar">
            <ul class="nav-inner">
                <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My JavaScript code is

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "about.htm"
    });
});
```

the page about.htm is in the same folder that the `index.htm` is placed.

I think I'm stuck please help.

Update:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'file:///C:/Users/Raymond%20Thomas/Desktop/JavaScript%20Tutorial/about.htm'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin
>   requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome,
>   chrome-extension, https.

this is the error logged in console

Comment: sounds like you are not running this on a localhost server. Can't use ajax in `file://` protocol

Answer (score 1):

Works fine the problem was I've tried to run the page without a server. It works fine when I run it in localhost.